# How to limit search to not show price in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

Hi currently the realtime search will display everything including icon and price.  For example if I type spice it will show a bunch of spice in the database as well as icon and price.  What I like to do is limit it only show the search query and/or icon but not the price.  Is this possible?  thanks.

Comment: Hide price from css no need to change code

Comment: @Ketan ok thanks can you point to the css that needs to modify?

Comment: Are you using any extension?share URLof website